# Looking for an Evernote alternative with password lock

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, software-recommendation, productivity

I am looking for an Evernote alternative with the following requirements:

- Cloud syncing
- iPhone and iPad app
- passcode lock (with encryption) - Yes, Evernote can encode notes, but only from the desktop client. And I would prefer 1 global lock rather than encrypting all my notes one-by-one
- Evernote's rich text editor sucks and cannot be turned off, but I prefer plaintext
- An OS X native app would be great (but I don't mind if it's web only for the desktop)
- Nice to have: lists (like Wunderlist)
- Nice to have: private sharing with friends / colleagues / family members

Have you come across such an app?

Answer (score 1):

I guess **[SimpleNote](http://simplenoteapp.com/)** meet your requirements.

- It does sync to the cloud.
- The iOS app is universal
- You can lock the app with a passcode
- It's plaintext only
- There's no SimpleNote desktop app *per se*, but there's a public API and a lot of great software use it that you can find [here](http://simplenoteapp.com/downloads/).
  And there's also a web app
- There's no list, but there are tags.
- You can share your notes.